# When change a option how to get a simple product id from configurable product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

When change a option how to get a simple product  id  from configurable product in magento 2

[image]

> custom .phtml file

```
<script>
   require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
], function($){
     $('body').on('click', '.swatch-option', function(e) {
        var swatchid = $('.swatch-attribute').attr('option-selected');
        var swatchattributeid = $('.swatch-attribute').attr('attribute-id');
        alert(swatchattributeid);
    });

});

 </script>
```

i get a option id like this

[image]

Comment: You want to get in js file or in other file?

Comment: other custom phtml file

Comment: Did you tried this? https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-extract-currently-selected-product-id/